# Excel 2010: VBA to delete columns with headers containing text across multiple tables/worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have macros to dynamically create columns (via an "Add" button) in tables across multiple sheets in my workbook, in some cases on sheets containing multiple tables.  I would like to also have a "Remove" button that finds all columns containing text "toolname" in all tables in the workbook and deletes them.

I've tried a few different loops but am not sure how to go about actually finding and deleting columns based on said text, whether it should be a structured reference or a range, etc.  Pretty big vba noob here so any help in the right direction would definitely be appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? `.Find()`?

Comment: @BruceWayne - *'tried a few different loops'* but apparently they are xlSheetVeryHidden.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to find what you are looking for ?

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Cells.Find(What:="toolname", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
                False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
   'if no matches is found
End If
```